# Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject ( Volley Android Php API)

Tags: java, php, android

Hello I have a problem in volley api calling a REST Api writing in php , when I use another rest api It works, but when I use mine it doesn't, So I think the problem is in my php api but I can't find it .
Here's my php db connection :

```
<?php
  $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=android;host=localhost';
  $user = 'root';
  $password = '';

 try {
  $db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Connexion échouée : ' . $e->getMessage();
 }
```

my all_clients.php

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    if ($_GET['url'] == "auth")   {
             $username = $_POST["username"];
             $password = $_POST["password"];
            $stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? and password=?");
            $stmt->execute([$username,$password]); 
            if ($row=$stmt->fetch()) {              
                         $response["message"]="valid";       
            } else {
                           $response["message"]="invalid";
                    } 
                    echo json_encode($response);

                }
```

my android volley api code:

```
RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "http://192.168.11.100/webservice/all_clients.php?url=auth";

    StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            JSONObject json= null;;
            Log.d("ffhnf", response);
            User user = null;
            try {
                json = new JSONObject(response);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The error I get : Value ﻿ of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: What happens if you access the API directly from something like Postman or cURL?

Comment: It gives me a json object like so {
    "message": "valid"
}

Comment: So if you call the API from another application (postman, curl etc), you get the expected result? Then it doesn't really sound like it's the API that's the issue. Btw, you really shouldn't_ store passwords in plain text. You should hash the passwords using [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and only store and only store the hash in the database.

Comment: Yes , thank you,  it's just for testing purposes I'm changing that later

Answer (score 0):

Try using `JsonObjectRequest`

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("username", username);
obj.put("password", password);

JsonObjectRequest jor = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, obj,
new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
         // Here is your json
         json = response
    }
},
new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
         // Handle Error;
    }
});

rq.add(jor);
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response I've tried that and I got this error : org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject , but I don't have any <br on my api I don't know where it's comming from